# Unwanted exit after a while: Error can't convert str to float

Tags: python, linux, nohup

I have written a little script that reads every hour from a website and search for a certain string. This string is a number with which i want to calculate.

If i run the script with "nohup python3 /path/to/script &" it works for a while. After few hours somethimes some days or even weaks the script stops working with the error output in "~/nohup" that the float() can't convert the string in line 41.

```
line 41: current_value = float(html_content[temperature_pos_begin:temperature_pos_end])
```

Whole script: http://pastebin.com/AEY1Kafa

Comment: What is the string that doesn't convert?

Comment: Put it in a `try` block so you can catch the exception, and then print out the faulty string.

Comment: You should add some validation, that the `temperature_pos_begin` variable really has a valid value. If it doesn't, perhaps you should log the captured HTML so you can trace what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an exception handler to see what is causing the error. Perhaps they use some sort of placeholder if the temperature isn't available.

```
try:
    current_value = float(html_content[temperature_pos_begin:temperature_pos_end])
except ValueError:
    print "Failed to convert %r to a float"%html_content[temperature_pos_begin:temperature_pos_end]
    current_value = None # or something that makes sense
```